# Wordpress System Requirement for Older Versions?

Tags: installation

Is there a place I can see what WordPress recommended for system requirements at the time of a certain release?

I can see the current requirements [HERE](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) and the previous releases [HERE](https://wordpress.org/download/releases/), but can't find more details on system requirements for each release.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily fetch the history of that page [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131101000000*/https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/), using Wayback Machine. Cheers.

Comment: Good thinking!  Not the most ideal way but possibly the only way.